# Error in dbListFields(con, VisitDetails) : object 'VisitDetails' not found

Tags: r, dbi

I am using sql server database in R. And trying to build a data frame with col1, col2. But while raise a query for list of fields in table **"VisitDetails"** it throwing error.

```
dbListFields(con, VisitDetails)
```

Can anyone tell me why I am not able to list the fields of table?
Where did I wrong for the above syntax?

"con" is the connection to sql server with login.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you can see from `?dbListFields`, your second argument (VisitDetails) should be a character string. Have you tried using  `dbListFields(con, "VisitDetails")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with **dbListFields(con, "VisitDetails")**.

It works.